# Why is ActiveRecord/PostgreSQL not finding my data in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm sure this is something simple I'm overlooking but since I've been dealing with this strange issue for a few days now I'm asking for help.

#### Here is my apps setup and the issue:

A Rails 3.2.13 app with the pg gem and the following db scheme:

```
create_table "clients", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "uuid"
  t.string   "private_key"
  t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
end

add_index "clients", ["private_key"], :name => "index_clients_on_private_key"
add_index "clients", ["uuid"], :name => "index_clients_on_uuid"
```

#### I currently have two rows in my "clients" database. They pictured below:

[image]

#### The issue

When I perform a simple "SELECT * FROM clients;" using the RubyMine database console I get the rows pictured in the screen shot above. When I perform a "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id = 11;" I get that row, all is well there. However, the issue is that when I try to perform a "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE private_key = "MkRBNUZBQzUtMzVDRi00NzQ3LThFNjEtNjI4OThERUQzQkRF";" it fails and shows the following in the console output...

```
sql> SELECT * FROM clients WHERE private_key = "MkRBNUZBQzUtMzVDRi00NzQ3LThFNjEtNjI4OThERUQzQkRF"
[2013-04-17 20:09:51] [42703] ERROR: column "MkRBNUZBQzUtMzVDRi00NzQ3LThFNjEtNjI4OThERUQzQkRF" does not exist
  Position: 43
```

I've also tried pulling this row out of the db by utilizing the active record helper methods...

```
Client.exists?(:private_key => token)
Client.find_by_private_key(token)
```

However, nothing works, it never finds the record that does exist in the db. Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? All I need to be able to do is utilize the active record helpers, specifically the "Client.exists?(:private_key => token)" to be able to check and see if the supplied token exists in the db.

Thanks for your help!

### Update 4/18/13 @ 9:30am

I just tried `Client.find(12)` just to see if it would find the record by id, and this works. This doesn't help me understand why I still can't use `Client.exists?(:private_key => token)` or `Client.find_by_private_key(token)`.

### Update 4/19/13 @ 9:15am

The answer to this problem was that the code generating my private_key value was adding a return/white space to the end of the value. So when trying to query the db for row based on a private_key it was always failing to find anything.

To fix the problem I added a gsub to the end of the code that generates the private_key, like this...

```
private_key = SecurityHelper.encrypt_private_key(client_uuid).gsub(/\s+/, "")
```

This strips all white space from the generated private key and solved the problem.

Comment: What do you get when you do `Client.all`?

Comment: @garbagecollection, I just tried ```Client.all``` and it did find both rows in the table. However, nothing else seems to work. Any idea why I can't simply ```Client.exists?(:private_key => token)``` or ```Client.find_by_private_key(token)```?

Comment: Can you use Ruby debugger and check if `token` value actually is the value that one of the clients has?

Comment: @garbagecollection, I have been using the Ruby debugger to check this and the value of "token" matches the exact value of one of the rows' private_key.

Comment: Can you try this? `Client.all.select {|c| c.token == token }` Worst comes to worst, if that works, you can use that. If this works, and  `Client.exists?(:private_key => token)` doesn't, I think that means that `pg` adapter is using wrong postgresql call for Ruby method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Client.exists?(:private_key => "MkRBNUZBQzUtMzVDRi00NzQ3LThFNjEtNjI4OThERUQzQkRF")
```

Comment: Can you successfully do Client.find(11)? If so, what is the string length of the private key? Perhaps you have a nonprinting character in the string.

Comment: See my update in the original post. I am able to pull rows out of the database utilizing ```Client.find(11)```. I checked the length of the private_key and it is 48 characters long. It is 48 characters in the database and ```token.length``` returns 48.

Comment: Puzzling. Does Client.exists?(:uuid => uuid_token) work (where uuid_token has the correct value for record 11)?

Comment: Fred, your last comment helped me to uncover the problem! I was able to successful query the db for the row containing a certain uuid. SO that got me thinking, there has to be something wrong with my private_key values. So I just inserted a new row manually and it now works. So I've narrowed it down the the code that is generating my private_key's as being the cause. I'm back in business, thanks!

Comment: I'm marking yours as the accepted answer. It isn't exactly the "answer" but it will help anyone in the same situation narrow down what might have been the cause.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong quoting style. ANSI SQL quoting as used in PostgreSQL is:

```
 "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE private_key = 'MkRBNUZBQzUtMzVDRi00NzQ3LThFNjEtNjI4OThERUQzQkRF';"
```

Note the single quotes.

It isn't clear how the first statement even got parsed by Ruby, since the inner double quotes would've ended the quoted string, leading to:

```
"SELECT * FROM clients WHERE private_key = "MkRBNUZBQzUtMzVDRi00NzQ3LThFNjEtNjI4OThERUQzQkRF";"
                                           ^^^^
                                           should be Ruby syntax error here
```

I don't really do Rails so I can't speak for the correct Rails syntax to do this check via ActiveRecord, though.

Comment: I tried pulling a row through the RubyMine database console again using the single quote as you suggested. This time instead of it saying, "[2013-04-17 20:09:51] [42703] ERROR: column "MkRBNUZBQzUtMzVDRi00NzQ3LThFNjEtNjI4OThERUQzQkRF" does not exist"
It said, "[2013-04-18 08:56:11] 0 rows retrieved in 61/79 ms". So it is still not finding the data which IS in the database.

Comment: @JeremyFox Please show the exact SQL that Ruby generated for that query.

Comment: I don't know exactly what the query is that Rails generates when using an active record helper (in my case ```Client.find_by_private_key(token)```). But I suspect it is something like a standard ```SELECT * FROM clients WHERE private_key = 'MkRBNUZBQzUtMzVDRi00NzQ3LThFNjEtNjI4OThERUQzQkRF';```